# jquery event not triggering after outside click

Tags: jquery, html

After entering value in the below postcode input type, the JS will check whether the user has entered correct post code or not. If the format is incorrect, JS will add a label(Incorrect Post code) dynamically. Now, the issue is once the error message is triggered, the margin-bottom space is not sufficient. I've added the below jQuery, but only the if condition is picking even after entering correct post code.

HTML:
    
        
        Postcode
        *

```
    <input type="text" maxlength="8" name="epicPostCode" id="epicPostCode" class="VAL_required VAL_postCode idleField omniErr(CE:Post_code_empty) omniDef(CE:Post_code_format_wrong)" value=""> 
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#epicPostCode").live("change", function(){
  $("label[for='epicPostCode']").each(function(){
    if($("label[for='epicPostCode']").filter("error")){
            $('#epicPostCode').parent().css('margin-bottom', '15px');
    }
    else {
        $('#epicPostCode').parent().css('margin-bottom', '0px');
    }
  });   
});
```

Comment: I suggest use `.on()`

Comment: We are using bit old jQuery library. So .on() won't work.

Comment: Using `.css`, in this instance, is doing it the hard way. This problem should resolve itself if you `.addClass("bottmarg15")` *(as an example)* to the appropriate element at the same time you are adding the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( "#epicPostCode" ).change(function() {    

  $("label[for='epicPostCode']").each(function(){
    if($("label[for='epicPostCode']").filter("error")){

            $('#epicPostCode').parent().css('margin-bottom', '15px');
    }
    else {

        $('#epicPostCode').parent().css('margin-bottom', '0px');
    }
  });   
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But still it is picking only the if condition.